# PHP PDO MySQL function doesn't edit data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have problems with this code, doesn't work good and don't edit data

edit.php

```
<?php
 $data = array(':news_id' => $_POST['news_id'] , ':news_title' => $_POST['news_title'] , ':news_content' => $_POST['news_content']);

$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "";
$DB_name = "acp";
try {
  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
  $dbh -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  /*if (isset($_POST['news_id'])) {
    $query = "UPDATE news SET 'news_title'=:news_title, 'news_content'=:news_content WHERE news_id=:news_id";
    $sth = $dbh -> prepare($query);
    $sth -> execute($data);
  } */

  $id = isset($_GET['news_id']) ? $_GET['news_id'] : NULL;
  $sth = $dbh -> prepare("UPDATE news SET `news_title`=:news_title, `news_content`=:news_content WHERE `news_id`=:news_id");
                    $sth -> bindValue(":news_id", $_GET["news_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth -> bindValue(":news_title", $_GET["news_title"]);
  $sth -> bindValue(":news_content", $_GET["news_content"]);

  $sth -> execute();
  $sth -> closeCursor();

  header('Location: ../news_admin.php');
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$dbh = null;
?>
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: **doesn't work good** doesn't help us understand what the problem is. Define what "*work*" means by explaining what you wanted the code to do that it's not doing or what the code did that you didn't expect it to do.

Comment: Are you sure you have those bindvalue parameters in GET, that is in the url? You might need $_POST

Comment: @Sherif, i writing news system and this function doesn't work, mysql can't change my last data to new data.

Comment: @Mihai i too use $_POST and too doesn't work.
sorry for my english guys.

Comment: @imphoenix You still haven't provided any error information.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/A0LUiK3d html form

Comment: @Sherif Notice: Undefined index: news_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\pizzeria\ap\includes\edit.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: news_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\pizzeria\ap\includes\edit.php on line 20

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting errors here. You're not using the right delimiter for columns:

```
UPDATE news SET `news_title`=? ...
```

Note that you're using single quotes like `'news_title'` in the first statement. That is a string, not a column, and updating a string makes no sense in SQL.

I'd avoid using delimiters unless your column names overlap with [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html), and avoid naming columns that way in the first place.

Since you're capturing exceptions I'd make sure that your error reporting is working correctly. Executing a deliberately bad query would be one way to verify this is working.

Comment: @tadman i edit to it and too doesn't work :/ i'm a beginner programmer

Comment: So long as you have errors you have things to fix. You're going to have to try to isolate the problems.